# Self join with head id field

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a self-join table with a head table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LEZM.png).

My table B entity is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class TableB implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Table_A_id")
    @Where(clause = "Parent_id IS NULL")
    private TableA headline;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Table_A_id")
    private TableB parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval= true)
    private List<TableB> child;

    ...
}
```

Now I am trying to insert table B but I usually get errors because the table B sub-line is usually lost the headline. Do I have any annotation for the headline field so I don't need to ensure that manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I answered on discourse (https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/self-join-with-head-id-field/5512) that's not possible.